# How to add different comment box in different link in php?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add facebook comment box in each article by using php code.

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div align="center"> <div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/sample" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div> </div>
```

Problem is that it displays same comment box in each url. I need to display different comment box in different url of my site. Is there any guidance. Please help me since I'm just new in php.

Comment: This isn't PHP, it's Javascript...

Comment: [developers comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments)

Comment: Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change this line:

```
<div align="center"> <div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/sample" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div> </div>
```

To something like this:

```
<div align="center"> <div class="fb-comments" data-href="<YOUR URL>" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div> </div>
```

for example

```
<div align="center"> <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://<?=$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];?>" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div> </div>
```

See [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#settings) for more information.

Comment: sorry to say that it didn't work. I changed as:                     <div align="center"> <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://localhost/sample/index.php?t=$fld_news_name&i=$fld_news_id" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div> </div>

Comment: I think thats because you're using a localhost and not a fqdn.

Comment: Yeah. Now I'm developing one newspaper's website in the localhost. I'm facing such problem. Once finished I'll upload it.